# Unable to find the socket transport "SSL" though phpinfo() show that OpenSSL support enabled

Tags: php, sockets, email, ssl, laravel-5

I am working with uduntu server. My php version is  5.5.9-1ubuntu4.5 (cli) (built: Oct 29 2014 11:59:10). In this server I have deployed a laravel 5.2 project in which I tried configure an email account from which will send password reset link. 
The problem is when I try to send email then I found the following error.

```
Swift_TransportException in StreamBuffer.php line 265:
Connection could not be established with host secure.emailsrvr.com [Unable to find the socket transport "SSL" - did you forget to enable it when you configured PHP? #32538]
```

When I check phpinfo() I find

```
OpenSSL support enabled
OpenSSL Library Version OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014
OpenSSL Header Version  OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014
```